# How to get/know/make ID column in Appendgrid (html/php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, lov

I got a case to make column insert using appendgrid.
In my case, I need insert data with LOV (list of values) or any plugin to appendgrid column.

Then my question is how to send data from LOV (or any plugins) to apppendgrid column.

Example below.
Thank you.

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you supply some more information? What kind of frameworks are you using? What is already working and what is not? Where is the data stored? What exactly do you mean by appendgrid (the jQuery Plugin)? What should be the result of clicking the button you highlighted in your screenshot?

Comment: I need to send the result of LOV to appendgrid column

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really supply any more useful information, so the best guess I have is the following (using the [documentation](https://appendgrid.apphb.com/Documentation)):

```
$(function() {
    $('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({
    // Object containing the definitions of the table rows
    initRows: RowDefinitons,
    // Your LOV Data
    initData: LOVData
    });
});
```